# convert fwrite in matlab to python

Tags: python, arrays, function, matlab, fwrite

I want to convert matlab code to python. This is to write the little_endian format file.
I appreciate if anyone can help me.
The matlab code is:

```
function fileformat(data, filename, type)
file_id = fopen(filename, 'wb','l');
fwrite(file_id , data, type,'l');
fclose(file_id );
```

The python code that dose not work correctly is:

```
def formatfile (data, dir_filename, dtype):
    f = open(dir_filename, 'wb')
    f.write(data) 
    f.close()
```

Comment: What is "data" in the Python code?

Comment: "data" in the Python code is something like image (int32; np array) that i want to write it in the little_endian format.